# How to capture request from blazemeter recorder

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am trying to capture http request by using blazementer recorder to export a smart jmx scipt but do not have any Idea.

Please  guide me that I accomplish my gaol

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this **[Record with BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/10/record-with-blazemeter-chrome-extension/).**

Hope, this will help you!!!